# VirtualBox: Have Scaled Mode respect aspect ratio

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using a virtual machine to play some old games.  Unfortunately, some of them are only at 800x600 or have some other 4:3 max resolution.  I want to stretch it to cover my monitor but I don't want it stretched to 16:9 ratio.  Is there a good way to do that without changing the resolution of my main monitor?

I've tried the Auto Resize option and Fullscreen mode, and both only use 800x600 pixels and did not work.

EDIT:  To clarify the issue and goal, I will include 4 pictures.  I am using Windows 2000 for this example.  This is the desktop with the dynamic resolution, properly at 1920x1080 (fullscreen mode).

[image]

This is what happens when I open a game.  The image is small. This behavior is inconsistent, as sometimes the black border is white:
[image]

And this is what happens if I enable scaling and maximize (can't seem to full screen while in scaled mode).  The image is stretched:

[image]

And this is a mockup of my goal I made.  I want the aspect ratio respected with the addition of black bars (except the text would be clearer):

[image]

I have an approach that works, which is to set actual monitor to 800x600 or another 4:3 ratio, but I would strongly prefer not having to do that every time I hop in and out of the game.

It occurs to me that it is possible this is a Windows 2000 setting issue rather than a Virtual Box issue.

For anyone who cares, the game displayed is Reach for the Stars released in 2000 or 2005.

Comment: You should be able to resize Virtual Box on your host so as to permit the resolution you want in the guest machine. I cannot say for sure.  I DO resize my guest properly with VMware Workstation Pro. Did you install VBOX extensions in the Guest machine?

Comment: @John OP wants the guest to be upscaled without changing the resolution when resizing the host window.

Comment: I understand that, but I do resize VMware Workstation to help with Guest resizing. That is because, if the host has strange or different size, guest may not resize properly. I use both and after a very long time with virtual machines, that works best for me.

Comment: @John, I do have the guest extensions installed.  I can turn on dynamic resolution, but if I do that in my games, they automatically resizes the screen to the smaller size.  I will add images to the question show what is happening.